# Video play library using CSR JSLink

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-side-rendering, video, asset-library

Can we have video playing library to be added in SharePoint online page by using CSR JSLink customization?
[image]

I want to customize the video player like the attached image above. Anyone suggest the feasible solution for this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can have this type of video library using CSR JSLink. Left hand side portion with Content editor webpart and add the HTML code directly with Iframe.
Right hand side part should be CSR JS link of Asset video library.We can have the anchor tag with Target of that iframe name. So once click on that link the new video playing in that frame.

Thanks.